# calculate the tile of rotation axis of a rolling ball

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

I want to solve the problem of friction effect on rotation axis of a rolling ball on collision with another ball.

I've read Tennis racket theorem in [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tennis_racket_theorem) wikipedia article and thought it might help.

But according to wikipedia :
**For bodies with constant density an axis of rotational symmetry is a principal axis.**

Assuming the ball has constant density, this means the ball will always rotate around its principal axis, and even if it doesn't I can't determine the first,second,third principal axes as the ball have more than three(every diameter can be a principle axis).

So how to solve this problem ?

Comment: A spherical symmetrical object will have the same moment of inertia around any axis, so you are free to choose the direction of the principle axes. So the Tennis racket theorem will not be really applicable in this situation. But could you elaborate a bit more about what problem you try to solve? You want to simulate a ball which rolls on the ground and collides with another ball?

Comment: @fibonatic I want to solve the problem of two colliding balls, I want to determine their rotation axes after collision , exactly the effect of friction on those axes.